# Wh clause usage

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, american-english, british-english

Please find the below sentence,

“The person is reading, who never gets tired.”

In above sentence, is ‘wh’ caluse referring to subject? or how the subject of the sentence is replaced with the ‘wh’ clause?

I know the ‘wh’ caluses referring object of sentence but having doubt in replacing subject of sentence by Wh clause.

please explain me in better way.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence that you proposed is not good English. Relative clauses that modify a noun immediately follow that noun. (There may be some weird special cases that differ, but immediately following is the general rule.)

Thus either of the following is correct.

**The person, who never gets tired, is reading.**

**The person who never gets tired is reading.**

In spoken English, the relative clause bracketed by commas in writing, would be separated by brief pauses.

The two sentences have slightly different meanings. In the first, where the relative clause is bracketed, the relative clause is descriptive and not essential to the intended message that the person is reading. In the second, the relative clause is restrictive and just as important to the intended message that the person is both reading and has a significant attribute.

Comment: in that case, can you tell me, which one of the following statements is correct?     1. That person is very nice, who never gets angry. 2. That person who is very nice, never gets angry.

Comment: The first sentence is far from idiomatic. Your examples are not particularly helpful because the ideas are so closely related. "The woman, who was short and slim, was reading aloud to the class." The two thoughts are discrete, and the subordinate clause is marked off with commas in writing and with slight pauses in speech. "The woman who was reading aloud to the class was not a regular teacher." Here the relative clause is essential to the thought because it identifies which woman was not a regular teacher.